# Discord BOT, I want to send everyone a random quote except to ONE user

Tags: python, discord, command, bots

I'm not a dev, I used to learn HTML and CSS back in the days but anyway, just trying to make a funny BOT for a couple friends on a Discord server and I can't actually find the solution to my problem.

Basically, my bot will send random quotes and everything works so far, but I want this ONE user not to receive a quote but to receive a very mean message. So far so good, he does receive the message but the BOT also sends him a random quote and I'd like it not to.

Here's my code, probably chaotic but hope it will help understand so far what the BOT does and if you could help me by letting me know what I could do in order to solve that problem. Of course, copy and paste your solution would be great but I'D LOVE if you could explain to me why and when and how you use this code and blah blah blah, you get me, I wanna learn.

Thanks a lot everyone ! :)

P.S I know the str(message.author) == Username#### isn't the best way but I haven't figured out yet how to make it work with the UserID

```
import discord
import os
import requests
import json

client = discord.Client()

def get_quote():
  response = requests.get ("https://zenquotes.io/api/random")
  json_data = json.loads(response.text)
  quote = json_data[0]['q'] + " -" + json_data[0]['a']
  return(quote)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}  '.format(client))

  @client.event
  async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
      return
  
  @client.event
  async def on_message(message):
    if str(message.author) == "Hakuna#1721":
      await message.channel.send('Nic, tu pues, vas te laver !')
 
    if message.content.startswith('&inspireme'):
      quote = get_quote()
      await message.channel.send(quote)


client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: soutiens a Nic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your code is written now, if the author's name is `"Hakuna#1721"`, you'll send them a mean message, but then you just continue on to the next if-statement. You want to do one or the other, but not both. I think all that's missing is a `return` statement in the first if-statement. So, this:

```
@client.event
  async def on_message(message):
    if str(message.author) == "Hakuna#1721":
      await message.channel.send('Nic, tu pues, vas te laver !')
 
    if message.content.startswith('&inspireme'):
      quote = get_quote()
      await message.channel.send(quote)
```

Would become:

```
@client.event
  async def on_message(message):
    if str(message.author) == "Hakuna#1721":
      await message.channel.send('Nic, tu pues, vas te laver !')
      return
 
    if message.content.startswith('&inspireme'):
      quote = get_quote()
      await message.channel.send(quote)
```

Now, if you send a mean message to your specific user, you terminate the function at that point. You could also write:

```
@client.event
  async def on_message(message):
    if str(message.author) == "Hakuna#1721":
      await message.channel.send('Nic, tu pues, vas te laver !')
 
    elif message.content.startswith('&inspireme'):
      quote = get_quote()
      await message.channel.send(quote)
```

Note the change from `if` to `elif` to make the two options mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thanks Paul, it was that simple and I was looking way too far. Now I understand better the "return" command. Have a good one !